# Office 365 multi-user trial?

Tags: office365

I've have a UWP app which allows users to access their OneDrive files however I've only tested it against my trial developer account.

Is it possible to get a multi-user trial purely for testing purposes?  I have an Azure account.

Thanks

Comment: This question has nothing to do with programming, therefore it's off-topic on this site.

Answer (score 0):

No, you need to purchase a license for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can get time-limited trials from here: https://products.office.com/en-us/business/office-365-enterprise-e3-business-software

The trial version will be fully functional for 30 days, then less and less, but will remain accessible for ca. 60 days more (90 total).

It is perfect for testing purposes, especially if you suspect something may break. The only problem is recreating the users and all the settings. The advantage - you can start fresh and clean for every project.

You can always use ready scripts for pre-provisioning your environment or create one to answer your needs:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn800987.aspx
https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Set-up-full-SharePoint-3428f5a9